# Insert custom type object to postgres db from node.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, insert

I have angular and node.js app, and i try to insert into postgres db custom type, which looks like this:

CREATE TYPE t_speed AS (
time Date,
speed integer
);

this is my table:

`CREATE TABLE activities ( id_sportman integer, start_date timestamp, id_type_activity integer, distance numeric, id_district integer, name varchar(255), gpx_file_name varchar(255), gpx_file text, time_in_seconds integer, speeds t_speed );`

i am unable to insert new record from node.js:

`const postActivity = async (pool: any, req: any) => {
let activity = req.body;
let file = req.file;

const tcxDestination =
"path";

const newFilePath = tcxDestination + "/" + file.filename;

const tcxContent = await fs.readFile(newFilePath, "utf-8");
const { startTime, timeInSeconds, distanceInKm} = await extractDataFromGpx(tcxContent);

const data = {
time: new Date(),
speed: 120
};

await pool.query(
`INSERT INTO activities(id_sportman, start_date, id_type_activity, distance, id_district, name, gpx_file_name, gpx_file, time_in_seconds, speeds) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, 1, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9)`,
[
activity.idSportman,
startTime,
activity.idTypeActivity,
distanceInKm,
activity.name,
newFilePath,
tcxContent,
timeInSeconds,
data,
]
);
};`

it always say:
error: malformed record literal: "{"time":"2024-02-06T13:29:50.252Z","heart_rate":120}"

i tried change data type from date to timestamp, but nothing work, i also tried send date as string but it also do not work

can you help me, please?

ok, i found out how send one object, but what if i want send array of objects, can you help me please?

Comment: have you tried storing as JSONB?

Comment: Your custom type value needs brackets - `await pool.query(INSERT INTO activities(id_sportman, start_date, id_type_activity, distance, id_district, name, gpx_file_name, gpx_file, time_in_seconds, speeds) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, 1, $5, $6, $7, $8, ($9, $10)), [activity.idSportman, startTime, activity.idTypeActivity, distanceInKm, activity.name, newFilePath, tcxContent, timeInSeconds, data.date, data.speed]);`

Comment: but what if wont to send array of objects to database?